# React js - Uncaught TypeError: records.map is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mern

I'm working on a personal project using MERN Stacks, and I really can't prevent this error when trying to load Mongodb data

```
Uncaught TypeError: records.map is not a function
```

I'm trying to display data that is in the the database into my view that'll display then in the admin interface this is how the full view's code look like:

```
import { useEffect , useState } from 'react'
import '../adminInterface.css'
import RecordList from './recordList'




const Productsadmin = () => {

    const [records, setData] = useState(null)

    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchdata = async () => {
            const data = await fetch('http://localhost:5000/api/getproducts/')
            const json = await data.json()

            if (data.ok) {
                setData(json)
            }
        }
        fetchdata()
        
        },[])




    return (
        <div className='main-page'>
          <img className='logo-admin' src='https://i.imgur.com/v10SbL4.png'></img>
          <div className='productsdata'>
            {records && records.map((record) => (
                <RecordList key={record._id} record={record} />
            ))}
          </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Productsadmin
```

and here's the recordlist.js code

```
const RecordList = ({ record }) => {
    return (
        <div className="record-details">
            <h4>{record.productName}</h4>
            <p><strong>Location : </strong>{record.location}</p>
            <p><strong>Photo : </strong>{record.photo}</p>
        </div>
    )
}

export default RecordList
```

also I've tried to log the data before trying to render it, and it works perfectlly

Comment: You define your records as null and you never assign it another value, so that's why

Comment: Maybe you should check whether your API is working correctly or not.

Comment: Indeed @Asma, it was some misspelt parameter that I haven't noticed till now

Answer (score 1):

In order to work correctly, you should initialize your records variable to an empty array, so that you could then use the map() method on it :

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import '../adminInterface.css'
import RecordList from './recordList'

const Productsadmin = () => {
  const [records, setData] = useState([]) // Initialize to an empty array

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchdata = async () => {
      const data = await fetch('http://localhost:5000/api/getproducts/')
      const json = await data.json()

      if (data.ok) {
        setData(json)
      }
    }
    fetchdata()
  }, [])

  return (
    <div className='main-page'>
      <img className='logo-admin' src='https://i.imgur.com/v10SbL4.png'></img>
      <div className='productsdata'>
        {records.map((record) => (
          <RecordList key={record._id} record={record} />
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Productsadmin
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two errors in your code. Please check this Expo Snack (for RN, but same logic): https://snack.expo.dev/@zvona/async-fetch

I'll elaborate:

1. for type safety, use an empty array for init: `const [records, setData] = useState([]);`
2. for handling JSON data, please confirm it's an *Array*, not an *Object*:

```
if (data.ok && Array.isArray(json)) {
  setData(json);
}
```

Both of these are resolved in the example above with correct functionality.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set initial state value as blank array as like

**const [records, setData] = useState([])**
then you can run your code.

I have also handled the error if Array is empty then it's showing **No Record message.**

```js
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import '../adminInterface.css'
import RecordList from './recordList'

const Productsadmin = () => {
  //set empty array
  const [records, setData] = useState([]) 

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchdata = async () => {
      const data = await fetch('http://localhost:5000/api/getproducts/')
      const json = await data.json()

      if (data.ok) {
        setData(json)
      }
    }
    fetchdata()
  }, [])

  return (
    <div className='main-page'>
      <img className='logo-admin' src='https://i.imgur.com/v10SbL4.png'></img>
      <div className='productsdata'>
        {records.length>0 ? 
            records.map((record) => (
              <RecordList key={record._id} record={record} />
            )):
              <p>No Record</p>
        }
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Productsadmin
```